# What are number of hidden layers in LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I new to LSTM. I have not understood some terms used while implementing it in tensorflow. So I have ECG data, with each event having 60 heartbeat templates with each heartbeat template having 600 data points. (like each sentence having x words and each word represented by y size vector). So 600 amplitute points as a function of time comprise of each template and I have 60 of those and they together form one event having some class assigned to it. In all, I have 5000 such events classified in 4 classes. Now, suppose I want to classify them using LSTM, what are my input dimention for "num_hidden" if I am trying to follow the [code given here for MNIST data](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py)?

num_input = 60

timesteps = 600

num_hidden = ?

num_classes = 4

Also, I don't understand what this "num_hidden" is? LSTM, [as described here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), doesnot contain such a parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking two questions here.

`num_hidden` is simply the dimension of the hidden state.

The number of hidden layers is something else entirely. You can stack LSTMs on top of each other, so that the output of the first LSTM layer is the input to the second LSTM layer and so on. The number of hidden layers is how many LSTMs you stack on top of each other.